# How to get the value returned by a function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have simply functions to set new subject and mark:

```
public setSubject(subject) {
    return subject;
}

public setMark(mark) {
    return mark;
}
```

I want `setSubject()` to return a string with the subject name and `setMark()` to return a number. I call them in another function `matFn()`:

```
public matFn(){
var subject="Maths";
this.setSubject(subject);
}
```

For every subject I have function which gets subject name and call `setSubject()` with this subject as an argument.
In another function `getData()` I want to display them (next step will be the functionality, but let's start with console.log):

```
public getData() {
    var subject = this.setSubject();
    var mark = this.setMark();
    console.log(subject)
    console.log(mark)
}
```

I want to display exactly what setSubject() and setMark() returns. How would I do that?

Comment: You are not passing parameters ,other than your code looks good. what's your actual expectation??

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for getter and setter , you can try like below

```
class SomeClass {
   private _subject:string = "";
    get subject():string {
        return this._subject;
    }
    set subject(value:string) {
        this._subject = _subject;
    }
}

let someClassObj= new SomeClass();
obj.subject="hellow"
```

You can read the same

```
console.log(obj.subject)
```

**Another Approach**

declare a variable to set the value , you can read later when need

```
subject:string="";
public setSubject(subject) {
    this.subject=subject;
}
```

if the method is in same class  you can access with `this` object on your method want to access

```
console.log(this.subject)
```

Else you have to create an instance of the class.

```
let subjectClass=new Subject();
console.log(subjectClass.subject)
```

**Sample Code**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fr8jro?file=SubjectClass.ts

Comment: I would do it if I had subject hard coded but I need to set it with matFn(). I think that matFn() could return subject string but still I don't know how to get value returned by a function. P.S. I edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: @mikolaj  the return value will be the same value as a argument in the function. you don't need to call a value returned by a function. just simply log console.log(this.setSubject('maths')) , it will output 'maths'

Comment: @mikolaj In every programming language it's like that , I think you are missing something. Please clear your thoughts and update the question please

Comment: So I do this in matFn() but I need access to it from getData()

Comment: @mikolaj now I think I got your requirement , you want to read the subject you set in another function I am I right??

Comment: @JameeIM if you have solution please share it ;)

Comment: @mikolaj Updated the answer , You can go with both getter and setter as wells as the second approach

Comment: @mikolaj I would suggest the first solution

Comment: It works but I need more. Now I get empty line in console. It displays while subject = " " and it doesn't update when I set new value. How to fiz that?

Comment: @mikolaj are you saying once you set the value , you can't read it from another function. Please make sure that the variable 'subject' you declared  not inside a function , it should be a global variable

Comment: @mikolaj share some sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fr8jro?file=SubjectClass.ts

Comment: @JameeIM you mentioned instalnce of a class. I don't have Subject class and I would prefer to avoid creating it to simplify.

Comment: @mikolaj  refresh the stackblitz link

Comment: Ok  I looked at your sample code and I created SubjectClass.ts but now I get an error that Subject is duplicated identifier (class Subject in SubjectClass.ts) and ... = new Subject in AverageWebPart.ts